# SocialSharing plugin on Ionic 3, incorrect preview image

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, socialshare, socialsharing-plugin

I am using the Social Sharing plugin from https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/social-sharing/ within my Ionic 3 app.

Within my code I have:

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
```

And then ..

```
this.socialSharing.share('Check out Fanslide - In Play Fantasy Football! ' + this.myShareLink, '', 'https://www.fanslide.com/assets/images/appicon-small.png', '');
```

I am specifying the URL to an image as the third parameter.

If I then open the app and activate the share then I see the attached. There is a thumbnail a "T" and a cursor. This isn't my image so I am not sure where this is coming from.

How can I make sure that the image URL I specify is shown as the thumbnail?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: FYI, I've searched through the plugin code base and can't see this default thumbnail so have no idea where it is coming from.

Comment: If you paste this link on whatsapp or facebook does the image appear?

Comment: Yes, the correct image shows but this is being draw from the OG tag on the page.  My issue is only with the thumbnail preview shown within the app